# gensim.similarities.docsim.Similarity returns empty when queried

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, jupyter-notebook, gensim

I seem to be getting all the correct results until the very last step. My array of results keeps coming back empty.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial to compare 6 sets of notes:

https://www.oreilly.com/learning/how-do-i-compare-document-similarity-using-python

I have this so far:

```
#tokenize an array of all text
raw_docs = [Notes_0, Notes_1, Notes_2, Notes_3, Notes_4, Notes_5]
gen_docs = [[w.lower() for w in word_tokenize(text)]
           for text in raw_docs]

#create dictionary
dictionary_interactions = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(gen_docs)
print("Number of words in dictionary: ", len(dictionary_interactions))
#create a corpus
corpus_interactions = [dictionary_interactions.doc2bow(gen_docs) for gen_docs in gen_docs]
len(corpus_interactions)
#convert to tf-idf model
tf_idf_interactions = gensim.models.TfidfModel(corpus_interactions)
#check for similarities between docs
sims_interactions = gensim.similarities.Similarity('C:/Users/JNproject', tf_idf_interactions[corpus_interactions],
                               num_features = len(dictionary_interactions))

print(sims_interactions)
print(type(sims_interactions))
```

with the output:

```
Number of words in dictionary:  46364
Similarity index with 6 documents in 0 shards (stored under C:/Users/Jeremy Bice/JNprojects/Company/Interactions/sim_interactions)
<class 'gensim.similarities.docsim.Similarity'>
```

That seems right so I continue with this:

```
query_doc = [w.lower() for w in word_tokenize("client is")]
print(query_doc)
query_doc_bow = dictionary_interactions.doc2bow(query_doc)
print(query_doc_bow)
query_doc_tf_idf = tf_idf_interactions[query_doc_bow]
print(query_doc_tf_idf)

#check for similarities between docs
sims_interactions[query_doc_tf_idf]
```

and my output is this:

```
['client', 'is']
[(335, 1), (757, 1)]
[]
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
```

How do I get an output here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the content of your `raw_docs`, this can be the correct behaviour.

Your code returns an empty `tf_idf` although your query words appear in your original documents and your dictionary. `tf_idf` is computed by `term_frequency * inverse_document_frequency`. `inverse_document_frequency` is computed by `log(N/d)`, where `N` is your total number of documents and `d` is the number of documents a specific term occurs in.

My guess is that your query terms `['client', 'is']` occur in each document of yours, resulting in an `inverse_document_frequency` of `0` and an empty `tf_idf` list. You can check this behaviour with the documents I took and modified from the tutorial you mentioned:

```
# original: commented out
# added arbitrary words 'now' and 'the' where missing, so they occur in each document

#raw_documents = ["I'm taking the show on the road.",
raw_documents = ["I'm taking the show on the road now.",
#                 "My socks are a force multiplier.",
                 "My socks are the force multiplier now.",
#                 "I am the barber who cuts everyone's hair who doesn't cut their own.",
                 "I am the barber who cuts everyone's hair who doesn't cut their own now.",
#                 "Legend has it that the mind is a mad monkey.",
                 "Legend has it that the mind is a mad monkey now.",
#                 "I make my own fun."]
                 "I make my own the fun now."]
```

If you query for

```
query_doc = [w.lower() for w in word_tokenize("the now")]
```

you get

```
['the', 'now']
[(3, 1), (8, 1)]
[]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I understand what you're saying, but just to clarify - you believe the issue may be that the phrase 'client is' being in each document creates a value of 0? I'm almost positive there are no phrases that appear in only 1 document. I found a phrase that appears in 4 of the 6 documents, but this also results in a similar issue.

Comment: Note that you don't query for a phrase (words in a particular order), but for a list of tokens where order does not matter. So yes, if **both** tokens `'client'`and `'is'` appear in **all** of your 6 documents, the tfidf of your query will be `0`. As a test, find a word that occurs in at least one document, but not all of them, and add that word to your query. See if this gets you any results.

Comment: That makes sense. I found a phrase (requested refund) that appeared in only 4 docs and got the same result. I made a test set of unique documents and ran it through and the code works. I'm guessing that this isn't an issue with the code but the issue you just stated. Therefore, this probably won't be a useful tool for me. Thanks very much for your help!